# CSS transform: matrix3d() - After transition, image pops back into place instead of easing?

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions, transition

I'm trying to implement a 3D matrix transform on an image. The transform works correctly as I hover over the image. However, I can't seem to make it transition back to its original placement smoothly. When I leave the image after hovering it pops back into place quickly, not a smooth transition.

(Also, I'm trying to ultimately mirror this transition - to make the image bend to the right instead of the left...any ideas?)

Tried so many different solutions - any help would be great!

JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0roefvye/

```
.rot {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}

.rot:hover {
  transform: matrix3d(0.9659258262890683, 0, 0.25881904510252074, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -0.25881904510252074, 0, 0.9659258262890683, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By applying a `transition` to any pseudo-class, such as `:hover`, that transition will only be applied when the element is in the associated state.

To achieve what you want you would therefore need to apply the `transition` to the `.rot` class:

```css
.rot {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  transition:transform 2s ease;
}
.rot:hover {
  transform: matrix3d(0.9659258262890683, 0, 0.25881904510252074, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -0.25881904510252074, 0, 0.9659258262890683, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="rot"></div>
```

As to the second part of your question, I'm not 100% sure on the exact effect you're attempting to achieve (could you edit your question to include an example?) but simply adding a `transform-origin` might do the trick for you:

```css
.rot {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  transition: transform 2s ease;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.rot:hover {
  transform: matrix3d(0.9659258262890683, 0, 0.25881904510252074, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -0.25881904510252074, 0, 0.9659258262890683, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="rot"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you SO much! Would you happen to know the values needed to create a transition to the right rather than the left?

Comment: Check the second Snippet I just added.

Comment: You're welcome :) If this has answered your question to your satisfaction, you might consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want same effect on mouse out  then you should put all delay, timing function etc. on the actual class, not on hover.

```css
.rot {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
   transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}

.rot:hover {
  transform: matrix3d(0.9659258262890683, 0, 0.25881904510252074, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -0.25881904510252074, 0, 0.9659258262890683, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
 
}
```

```html
<div class="rot"></div>
```

Comment: MASSIVE thank you! Any idea on the values needed to transform the image to the right instead of to the left?

Comment: using matrix3d? then I need to dig Internet?

Comment: Yeh, using matrix3d - instead of moving to the left as it currently does, bending to the right.

Comment: the best way is to use online CSS tool for this.